# codenvy.com - eclipse che - create a custom stack

Tags: neo4j, eclipse-che, codenvy

create a custom stack

i'm trying to run neo4j on codenvy, in order to achieve that i did  the following

1) created a new stack, adding a new machine with this configuration:

```
new-machine:
 image: neo4j/3.0
 mem_limit: 1073741824
```

2) create a new workspace with the runtime just created

3) imported a blank project into the workspace (just to import something)

making the workspace running no errors are displayed, so the questions are:

- is neo4j already running or i have to issue some command against that machine?
- what is the url to access to the neo4j console? knowing the port is 7474

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/2bf521bddb65542f583f157f798afa636660b712/3.5.3/community/Dockerfile) (see last line: `CMD ["neo4j"]`) the neo4j should be running after loading the image. The IP should be the one of your virtual machine, in my case:

```
macbook-pro:~ username$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.0
```

or simply run:

```
macbook-pro:~ username$ docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100
```